# Is "the" idomatic in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> That attitude is fostered by **the** American government.

Is "the" required in this sentence? Why?

"by the american governement" is way more frequent on the Internet than "by American government". But I suspect that the sentence is as good without that "the".

Comment: Are you assuming *government* is an uncountable noun in that meaning?

Comment: @userr2684291 Yes, I do.

Comment: Well, therein lies your problem. Normally you want a countable noun for that sense, and then, because there's only one such government, a definite article is appropriate. Using *government* uncountably refers to a type of government in a more vague, conceptual sense (as is the case with most uncountable nouns): *∅ democratic government*, *∅ federal government*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an *idiom*, but it *is* required in the sentence you have given.  When I read that sentence, I know that it is referring to a single entity — that is, the governing body of the United States of America.

There are reasonable ways to use "American government" without necessarily prefixing with **the**, but they would usually have slightly different meanings:

- *"American government attitudes can change over time"*
- *"American governments, past and present, have held the attitude"*

Among other things, if you did not have the specific use of **the** in your sentence, there is a potential for more subtle ambiguity.  For example, if written in a satirical piece, *"That attitude is fostered by American government"* could imply that, *"if you could govern America, you could foster that attitude*, where the meaning of **govern** changes to **influence** or **control**, and **foster** changes to **alter**.

As far as I can tell, the sentence you have written is *not* doing those manipulations.

Depending on the context of the piece, there are still two slight ambiguities to the sentence:

1. whether the author is saying that the attitude is one of the *current* government, or a generalisation of the common attitudes of the current and previous governments
2. whether the author is saying that the attitude is *held* by the government, or that the government is *engineering* or *cultivating* the attitude in its populace

In my personal opinion, it is probably that the attitude has been *held* by current *and* previous governments, but additional context could change this.